# If a finite sum is a unit, then it has a term that is a unit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

Source:

1. Theorem 19.1 (A First Course in Noncommutative Rings by T.Y. Lam)
2. [Local Ring on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring)

**Theorem 19.1**
For any nonzero ring R, the following statements are equivalent:
(1) $R$ has a unique maximal left ideal.
(2) $R$ has a unique maximal right ideal.
(3) $R/rad R$ is a division ring.
(4) $R$\ $U(R)$ is an ideal of $R$.
(5) $R$\ $U(R)$ is a group under addition.
(6) For any $n$, $a_1+...+a_n\in U(R)$ implies that some $a_i\in U(R)$.
(7) $a+b\in U(R)$ implies that $a\in U(R)$ or $b\in U(R)$.

In the sketch of the proof by Lam, its said that (4)=>(5)=>(6)=>(7) are tautologies.
Let $R$ is commutative and $R$ is a local ring then its satisfy (1) and (2), how to prove (6)?

Comment: What do you mean by "prove (6)"? The author is not saying that (6) is true in general. They're saying that if one of the 7 statements is true, then so is everything  else.

Comment: In particular, a question to ask would be "How to prove (6) $\implies$ (7)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean "prove 6 from 5" then I'll comment on that.

Suppose (5) holds and $\sum a_i\in U(R)$. Then if all the $a_i\in R\setminus U(R)$, it would follow from (5) that $\sum a_i\notin U(R)$ since $\sum a_i\in R\setminus U(R)$. So apparently one of the $a_i$'s has to fall in $U(R)$.

I guess you did not mean "prove 7 from 6" because 7 is just a special case of 6.